# How to fix discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] for cv::SVMParams?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a class ConfigFile that has a getter for the SVMParams member:

```
cv::SVMParams gerSVMParams()
{
  return *m_mapConfig["SVMParams"];
}
```

The code is a little bit more complicated. `m_mapConfig` is a

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr< IConfigItem > >
```

And `IConfigItem` is a template class that looks like this for `SVMParams`:

```
template<> class ConfigItem< cv::SVMParams > : public IConfigItem
{
private:
    cv::SVMParams m_value;

public:
    ConfigItem(const cv::SVMParams& valueIn) : m_value(valueIn) {}

    operator cv::SVMParams() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};
```

My problem is when I am trying to auto train the SVM classifier:

```
classifier.train_auto(trainingData, classes, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), configFileIn.getSVMParams());
```

I am getting an error of kind:

```
error: passing ‘const ConfigFile’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘cv::SVMParams ConfigFile::getSVMParams()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong? Or is there a small bug because because the `train_auto` functions has no const in front of the `SVMParams` parameter. Or is it modifying it?

Comment: btw, you seem to use an outdated version of the master branch ? it got a major refactoring this summer.

Comment: Yes, I know that there is OpenCV 3.0.0 beta, but I am not really in the mood to change all the application, because there is a major change.

Comment: ^^ understood. indeed, code looks quite different ..

Comment: It is based on [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63249/50647) post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I was calling the function in which I was calling the `getSVMParams()` with `const ConfigFile&`; and that was not allowed by the `shared_ptr` I used in the `map`.
Thanks all, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Make your function `const`:

```
cv::SVMParams gerSVMParams() const
//                           ^^^^^
```

The error is you are calling a non-const method on a const object, which the compiler rejects as being potentially unsafe. That said, your implementation is inherently non-const too since you might be inserting an object into your map, so just adding the `const` won't help.

What you probably want to do is:

```
cv::SVMParams gerSVMParams() const
//                           ^^^^^
{
    auto it = m_mapConfig.find("SVMParams");
    if (it != m_mapConfig.end()) {
        return *(*it);
    }
    else {
        return {}; // maybe?
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but It was not that the problem... It says: `error: passing ‘const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<IConfigItem> >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<...’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`